# cakephp session no new files in tmp/sessions

Tags: session, cakephp, updating, tmp

I am in the cumbersome proces of updating a Cakephp application from 1.2 to 2.5.

I discoverd that one of the main reasons I keep getting errors is because the sessions are not stored in tmp/sessions.

(each time a new browser visits the app a new session file should be added which is the case in the old version which still works and functions as base level)

-I did not change any settings to the TMP constant.

-In core the write setting for session is cake:

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

-I checked whether tmp folder and sessions folder are writable, they are.

What could be the reason that no new files are generated?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Ok I've resolved my issue which was similar to yours. I had a session_start php commandsomewhere in my code which overwrote all the core.php config, and basically it restored the php.ini session management settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396811/cakephp-session-being-written-to-tmp-and-not-app-tmp-sessions/25400740#25400740

Comment: Thx for your comments aDvo. I did not manage to resolve it. I will look for your solution in my code soon (after holiday)