# CakePHP Session being written to /tmp/ and not /app/tmp/sessions/

Tags: cakephp

Similar simple but unanswered question here:
[cakephp session no new files in tmp/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733151/cakephp-session-no-new-files-in-tmp-sessions)

I have Cake 2.4.x Running on a local WAMP server. My phpinfo() shows session.save_path of **c:/wamp/tmp**. I have verified this, login session currently have session files created in c:/wamp/tmp/.

I'm trying to convert to use cake session handling instead. According to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html , using 'cake' session handling - *Saves sessions as files inside app/tmp/sessions. This is a good option when on hosts that don’t allow you to write outside your own home dir.*

So i have placed this code inside my Core.php

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake'
    ));
```

Problem is I still don't see anything appearing under my app/tmp/sessions directory, but i still see session files being created in my c:\wamp\tmp directory.

**Question:
How do i get Cakephp to start writing sessions into application directories?**

Cheers
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting afresh by creating 2 cakephp tutorial blogs and testing them side by side for the dreaded session sharing, I realize that the following code worked there in creating session files in the respective cakephp installation app/tmp/sessions folders.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

But as it wasn't working for my existing application, I could only conclude that my existing application was the problem.

Looking at phpinfo() on all installations also told me that the cakeblog tutorials were successfully overidding the session.save_path value from php.ini, wher eas my actual cakephp application had the same value for local session.save_path  master session.save_path value (from php.ini). 
Which means that my core.php settings to use cake sessions were being overridden somewhere!!!!!

After hours of investigation i found the culprit.

I had in my app/webroot/index.php a line of code, which i inserted months before.

```
session_start();
```

This session_start() i inserted basically was overidding my cake core.php settings with the original php.ini settings. This "session_start()" i had placed in there was initially to overcome a login loop bug which I had with IE and Bluehost.com as the host. I've commented that line and the session files started appearing in the app/tmp/sessions folder.

HALLELUJAH!

Answer (score 1):

First time that i see this problem. Can you test :

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => '/app/tmp/sessions'
    )
));
```

[book cake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html)